# Is there any way i can set the ephemeral node deletion time

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I just wanted to know that whether is there a way by which i can change or `set the ephemeral node deletion time according to me` ? As per my knowledge its by default 30 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, ephemeral nodes are deleted in two cases:

1. when the session of the client, which created that node, times out
2. when client explicitly deletes the node

So, if you are not deleting any ZNode explicitly, setting the session time out as per your requirement is the only other way